# Можно ли ускорить парсинг ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml

С помощью `ElementTree` разбираю xml-файлы разного размера примерно по такому принципу:

```py
with open('filename.xml') as file:
    xml = ElementTree.fromstring(file.read())
offers = xml.findall('offer')

for offer in offers:
    do_smthng(offer)
```

Заметил, что чем больше элементов содержит `offers`, тем меньше итераций в секунду происходит. Есть ли какие-то способы парсить файлы так, чтобы скорость не зависела от размера объекта `offers`? И есть ли вообще какие-нибудь рекомендации по ускорению парсинга xml?

Answer (score 2):

ElementTree - это DOM-парсер, они плохо подходят для больших файлов. Для больших объёмов предназначены SAX-парсеры.

Comment: Спасибо, погуглю